# Calculate window function against another in same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

Hi I am using SQL server. I have a set of data and I am trying to use window functions to count the instances of something. I am then running the window function again and dividing it against a row count window function to try and get an average. However, I keep getting 0. Is it possible to run a window function against another in the same column?

```
COUNT(city) OVER (partition by state)/Count(*) over (partition by total)*100 AS AVG
```

is something like this possible? When i break it apart and run each individually it works, but when i combine them i get 0 in the column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of integer arithmetic -- nothing to do with window functions.  Write this as:

```
COUNT(city) OVER (partition by state) * 100.0 / Count(*) over (partition by total) AS AVG
```

The `100.0` puts a decimal point in the arithmetic.  So, 1/2 is 0.  But 1.0/2 is 0.5.

Comment: this works, any way you could explain in more detail about why moving the 100 and adding a decimal works?

Comment: Data types. `10/3=3` because the math reverts to dividing integers. And since integers don't have a decimal, this rounds down to `3`. Saying `10/3*1.0` still says to SQL Server that we're working with integers. It coerces all sides down to `3*1=3`. However, `10*1.0/3` says we're working with a decimal >> `10.0/3=3.3......`. You want the decimal in the output. When working with math variables, you have to watch the data types. If a variable can be converted from one datatype to another, it will when needed. And math order of operations says `*` and `/` go left to right.